# Where do I put my focus on my character sheet?

Tags: character-creation, world-of-darkness, mage-the-ascension

I'm making my first character for a World of Darkness (20th anniversary) campaign and right after backgrounds, I've gotten to a step where it says "Define Focus (paradigm, practice, instruments)"

What does this mean specifically, and where should I put the focus on my character sheet?

Comment: Are you playing M20? If not, then you might be using a completely wrong character sheet.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There are extended 2-page and 4-page versions of the [M20 Character Sheet](https://mrgone.rocksolidshells.com/m20.html) that have room for Focus and many more character details.

What Focus means exactly is a huge part of how Mage works:

> ### M20, page 62
>
> [F]ocus combines the mage’s beliefs about magick, the practice he follows, and the instruments he uses to direct that belief toward magickal results. All three elements are combined into a single unit: paradigm + practice + instruments = focus.
>
> For details about paradigms, practices, and tools, see Chapters Six (pp. 256 & 259) and Ten (pp. 529-530 & 565-600).